# How to change ConnectionString class dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project I am using a `ConnectionString` class. I want to change my `ConnectionString` class dynamically in my Winforms application.

I want to create a form (`frmServerCon`) where I can input new values in textboxes, like **Data Source**, **Initial Catalog**, **Username** and **Password**. When I click the "save" button, the code is supposed to save these new settings in the `ConnectionString` class and on connect button click it should check if new connection values work for SQL Server before saving.

Right now my `ConnectionString` class look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace 7KProject
{
    class ConnectionString
    {
        public string DBConn = "Data Source=TCP/IP,PORT;Initial Catalog=DataBase;User ID=user;Password=*******";

    }
}
```

I am unable to find any solution. It would be great if you can help with some working code. Sorry I have no example code.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel (yet again!) - there's already the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) that does pretty much what you're trying to do, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have sort out this problem in other way. I Hope it may help some other people looking for this and i would like to ask to review it if there is any improvement please do suggest.

i am calling app.config connectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConn" connectionString="Data Source=Servername;Network Library = DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

into my ConnectionString class.

```
public class ConnectionString
    {
        public string DBConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ToString();
    }
```

in the back end i have a created a form to add new server connection information to add new values to app.config connectionString. SvrConfig form

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace B4_HRM_System
{
    public partial class SvrConfig : Form
    {
        public SvrConfig()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try

            {

                if (txtserver.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Server Name.", "7KProject", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtserver.Focus();
                    return;
                }



                if (txtdb.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Database.", "7KProject", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtdb.Focus();
                    return;
                }

                if (txtuser.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Username.", "7KProject", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtuser.Focus();
                    return;
                }



                if (txtpass.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Password.", "7KProject", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtpass.Focus();
                    return;
                }

                string DBConn = "Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}";
                DBConn = string.Format(DBConn, txtserver.Text, txtdb.Text, txtuser.Text, txtpass.Text);
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                ConnectionStringsSection connSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
                connSection.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString = DBConn;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings");
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Completed", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }

        private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            b4login frmb4login = new b4login();
            frmb4login.Show();
       }

        }
}
```

but every time connectionString is saved i have to restart application. Is there any way or improvement for SvrConfig form when i close it updates/refresh connectionString in app.config file before showing login form so i don't have to restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the values separately, store them separately.  Something like this:

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
    public string InitialCatalog { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ConnectionString(string dataSource, string initialCatalog, string userID, string password)
    {
        DataSource = dataSource;
        InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
        // etc.
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}", DataSource, InitialCatalog, UserID, Password);
    }
}
```

Then you can create a `ConnectionString` object with the values you want, modify those values however you want, and any time you want the resulting connection string from that object you just call `.ToString()` on the instance of the object.

Basically, any time you have a string with multiple values contained therein, resist the temptation to *modify the string* for manipulating those values.  If you have separate values, then you have separate variables.  Keep separate things separate.  Only build the resulting string when you need it.

Comment: David i am still a noob, can you please tell me what should i use in //set the values here. and how i can work around this with form. i am looking for example code for class and form.

Comment: @Bukhalifa: What I mean by "set the values" is just to assign the supplied values to the class-level properties.  I've updated the code in the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing it the way you are doing it, but to build on your code, you should use a property not a field in the class.

So update your class this way:

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string DBConn { get; set; } = "your default string here";
}
```

Then somewhere else in your code you can get or set the property like this

```
var connectionString = new ConnectionString();
var dbConn = connectionString.DBConn; // get the value
connectionString.DBConn = "new string"; // set it with a new value
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a configuration file to store database credentials. When your application starts read the credentials and build a connection string. Store it and use to create a dbContext. Use your form to change the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a User string Setting:

**Properties > Settings:**

```
Name          Type    Scope  Value
MyConnection  string  User   Data Source=TCP/IP,PORT;Initial Catalog=DataBase;User ID=user;Password=*******"
```

Reading using:

```
string MyConn = Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnection;
```

And Saving using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnection = "...";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Unfortunately, the (ConnectionString) type is Application-scope (read-only), so use User-scoped "string" instead.  Also if you're going to store password, it'd probably be best to encrypt/decrypt that string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the NuGet package [Microsoft Data Connection Dialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog). It worked for me.